# Flutter How to set displayName with GetX?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I created a Firebase Auth with GetX.

And this is my createUser with Email and PW function;

```
void createUser(String name, String email, String password) async {
try {
  UserCredential _userCredential = await _auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

  User _yeniUser = _userCredential.user;
  await _yeniUser.updateProfile(displayName: name);
  String yeniUserID = _userCredential.user.uid; //User UİD'sini elde ettik
  await _firestore.collection("users").doc("$yeniUserID").set(
    {
      'eposta': email,
      'ad': _yeniUser.displayName,
      'saat': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'uid': yeniUserID,
      'aniVarmi': false,
    },
  ) ... //Catch things..
```

When I press the signup button, it creates firestore collection things except `'ad': _yeniUser.displayName,` it is always null.

I don't have userModel, I don't have database services. Just Authcontroller.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you share your updateProfile method?

Comment: I don't have a updateProfile method because I'm not giving this properties to User.

Answer (score 1):

after updateProfile try call

```
await _yeniUser.reload();
```

to refresh your user variable with updated display name.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your updateProfile method will return the user. So, you need to set your _yeniUser again like this:

```
_yeniUser = await _yeniUser.updateProfile(displayName: name);
```

Comment: This is not working but thank you for your answer.